# Tab bar background is missing on iOS 7.1 after presenting and dismissing a view controller

Tags: ios, uitabbar, ios7.1

I've tried my app on iOS 7.1 and I found that the tab bar background disappears on a few occasions. I was able to track them down; it happens when:

- pushing a view controller placed inside navigation controller (that is inside tab bar controller) with `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES`
- presenting a view controller and then dismissing it (i.e. the `MFMailComposeViewController`)

I've created a sample app (used the tab bar template + added button to display the view controller, and a mapView to be able to tell if the bar disappeared), and the issue is there.

[image]

Here is all the code for the sample app that I changed:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@import MessageUI;

@interface FirstViewController () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (IBAction)presentVCButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailer setSubject:@"Feedback for Routie"];
        [mailer setToRecipients:@[@"support@routieapp.com"]];
        [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Here you can download the whole [sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19940437/TabBarBugSample.zip).

Now, important thing: this seems not to affect iPhone 5, nor the simulator. The problem is on iPhone 4 and iPod Touch (last generation as of writing this post).

Does any of you have the same problem? Were you able to fix it?
Thanks!

**Update: I found a workaround. See my answer below.**

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue here. Were you able to fix it? And don't you have this another issue also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320964/ios-7-1-uibuttons-selected-state-not-working

Comment: yes, I was :). I am going to write the answer right now. Regarding the other issue: no, I don't have it.

Comment: Thanks for providing your solution. This bug is particularly tricky since it only happens on some devices (i.e. iPhone4). I am wondering why there is not more information available on the internet, I only found this SO thread after some intense googling...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Fix found!**

So after some investigating (and headache), I found out that there is a simple fix. Just toggle the `translucent` property, like this:

```
tabBar.translucent = NO;
tabBar.translucent = YES;
```

Now as for when to do this, there are several places for each case:

1) pushing viewController with `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES`
The bar background disappears right after the pop animation finishes, so add the fix to the `viewDidAppear:` method of the viewController that presented it:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = YES;
    ...
}
```

2) Presenting a view controller and then dismissing it:
In this case, the tab bar background is already gone during the dismiss animation. You can either do it in each viewController that you present separately, or, if you have subclassed `UITabBarController` (like I have), you can add it into its `viewWillAppear` method. Just be aware that calling the fix right away won't help (I've tried); that's why I used the dispatch_after GCD function:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.tabBar.translucent = NO;
        self.tabBar.translucent = YES;
    });
    ...
}
```

I know this is not the cleanest way, but it's clearly bug on Apple's side, and it's likely to stay with us for a while (I assume there won't be any iOS 7.2, so we'll most likely be stuck with this until iOS 8 comes out).

Comment: Another place to do the toggle is in a dismiss completion handler:[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){
        UINavigationController *delNC = self.navigationController;
        delNC.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
        delNC.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = YES;
    }];

Comment: Thanks. This crude workaround helped me with an iOS 8.0 issue where the tabBar didn't overlap anymore after a custom pop transition. However, I had to insert a `[tabBarController.view layoutSubviews]` in between the two lines. Also, this only works when `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` is not set for the tabBar.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the `-layoutSubviews` affected the `contentOffset` of my `UITableView` so the tableView scrolled for about half a row. To fix this I saved the contentOffset and re-applied it after the `-layoutSubviews`. A workaround for the workaround!

Comment: Unbelievable but this bug still exists in iOS 11.2.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, so I'll re-iterate the issue.  iOS 7 (on Device) Tab Bar becomes completely see-through on device, but works fine on Simulator.  Appears to happen after hitting `Back` from a detail page that has `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` enabled.

Setting the `Tab Bar Controller` > `Tab Bar` > `Background` to `White Color` in the `Storyboard` fixed it for me.  This fix keeps the translucency intact.

For some reason, toggling `tabBar.translucent` off and on again in `ViewDidAppear` did not work for me.

Using Xcode 6.3.1 with Swift.

Answer (score -1):

Go in your Main.storyboard and select your MKMapView to highlighted it (cf. in Navigator area you can select « Map View »). Then look carefully where is the bottom "white square": move it up the bottom bar! 
In the size inspector, you can check where you place the « anchor » or view origin for this view (cf. top-left hand side in your project). This explains why it’s ok for iphone 5 which has a bigger height screen.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the position of the tab bar is not the problem. Take a better look at the screenshot in my question: only the background is missing, the tab bar items are still there and it's still possible to change selected tab.
Regarding the size: latest iPod Touch also has 4", so it's screen-size independent.