# UITabBar has NO background color after transition

Tags: ios, background-color, uitabbar, transparent

I've got this app. When it launches, it asks the user to log in. When you log in, it uses `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight` to transition to a new `UIViewController`. The issue is, the `UITabBar` on the view controller has no background color. It is completely transparent. The `UITabBar` icons are there and it is otherwise fully functional, except that it has no background color.

This happened after I updated for iOS 7.1. Has anyone see this happen? If so, do you know how to fix it?

Apparently this issue has a "fix". This is obviously a bug on Apple's side.

[Here is it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327646/tab-bar-background-is-missing-on-ios-7-1-after-presenting-and-dismissing-a-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in iOS 7.1 on Apples's side. The work around is to toggle the translucency on and off. Not the best fix, but it works. We will have to wait until Apple fixes this in 7.2 or later.

```
tabBar.translucent = NO;
tabBar.translucent = YES;
```

As answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327646/tab-bar-background-is-missing-on-ios-7-1-after-presenting-and-dismissing-a-view)