# iOS Simulator 8.1 and 8.2 Translucency Bug with UITabBar?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, uitabbar, translucency

Is there any known Bug regarding the iOS Simulator and UITabBar for iOS 8.1 and 8.2? Today I noticed during testing that text heavily shines through the UITabBar when running in the 8.1 and 8.2 Simulators, while other iOS versions work flawlessly.

*I want to make sure there's no additional work needed, as the iOS 8 UINavigationBar translucent color drawing issues immediately came to my mind.*

**Demo Setup**

- Create fresh Tabbed App (using ObjC or Swift)
- Delete the First View and add a UITableViewContoller with dummy Static Cells

**Results**

Run the application, on iOS 8.1 and 8.2 Simulators the text shines through, on iOS 8.3 and above everything is working as expected.

Not related to Simulator Scaling, tested. Using a late 2013 rMBP with discrete GPU, El Capitan 10.11.2 and Xcode 7.2 (7C68). Working fine on device running iOS 9.

**Question: I don't have any iOS 8.x devices around anymore, can somebody please confirm (i.e. from memory) if that's simulator only or an OS bug? Or point to a rdar?**

Edit: Verified that it's not related to Swift, also happens with ObjC.
@maddy: Thanks for fixing the Tags!

Edit: Probably a regression related to this Bug with iOS 7.1: [Tab bar background is missing on iOS 7.1 after presenting and dismissing a view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327646/tab-bar-background-is-missing-on-ios-7-1-after-presenting-and-dismissing-a-view)

Cheers,
Frederik

[image: iOS Simulator 8.1]
[image: iOS Simulator 8.3]

Answer (score 1):

Many issues that are seen in the simulator are not simulator bugs but rather OS bugs that the simulator is revealing.

In this particular case, I think the issue is that there should be a blur getting applied to that layer behind the tab bar.  It may be the case that you have turned on the "Low Quality" option in the "Graphics Quality Override" (Debug menu).  Try turning that back to "Default" as that should cause all effects to be applied.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I am picky about and ask whether it's the simulator or a bug in the OS. Regarding the Graphics Quality Override: Checked that before, nope. Also checked it with gfxcardstatus both on GPU and discrete card.

Comment: Did you do what I suggested?

Comment: Sorry, pressed return to quickly ;) Yes, been there, did that. As a pixel perfect fullstack dev I always have this talent to stumble across this little UI glitches ^^ Edit: I am aware of a workaround (explicitly setting barTint just for iOS 8.0 to 8.2), I am just curious about *if* this is a known OS bug.

Comment: You made me aware to better rephrase and highlight my question. I am seeking for confirmation if it's actually an iOS Bug or just a simulator glitch. There are several cases where it's quite hard to tell, especially if not that many old devices are around where you're currently working.

Comment: Darn.  Then unfortunately, I have no answer for you, but I suspect it may be a sim bug.  If you can post a sample app somewhere (github), I can give it a go on an 8.2 device for you next week.

Comment: Here we go: https://github.com/winkelsdorf/iostabbarbugdemo. iPhone 6 8.1 to 8.2 fail, everything up is fine. Same for iPad. Let me know if you have a chance to test it with a device next week :)